# Custom dojo build doesn't include dojo.require()

Tags: build, dojo, custom-build

I have a legacy project that needs to be able to use dojo.require().

But I'm trying to build things in the newer builder format.  No matter what I do, I cannot get the custom dojo.js file built to have "require" in it.  I always get the error "dojo.require is not a function".

I don't really care about building my own dojo.js file, but I have to so I can exclude it from my custom layers.  Here's a shortened version of my build profile.

```
layers: {
    'dojo/dojo': {
        customBase: false,
        dependencies: []
    },
    'dojo/build/app': {
        include: [
            'dojo/fx',
            'dijit/dijit',
            'dijit/Dialog',
            'dojox/form/uploader'
        ],
        exclude: ['/dojo/dojo']
    }
```

Any thoughts or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to set this in my build profile.

staticHasFeatures: {
  'dojo-sync-loader': 1
}

Then dojo.require() is available.

I'm not positive, but this related line may be needed to prevent other issues:
  'dojo-xhr-factory': 1